# Geoserver authentication with Leaflet WFST

Tags: authentication, leaflet, geoserver, wfs

I've created a WFS service in Geoserver, and have been using the Leaflet WFS-T module for accessing the layer. So far, so good. But now I want to secure the WFS service. How do I access a secured WFS service using WFS-T? I don't have that much experience with javascript nor web development except for ESRI's WebAppBuilder, since I've been doing mostly desktop-programming (C#) in the past. Can you guys point me in the right direction on how to do this?

Comment: What is "the Leaflet WFS-T module", exactly? How are you using it so far?

Comment: It's a plugin for WFS-services... https://github.com/Flexberry/Leaflet-WFST

Comment: The usual trick is to send a basic authentication to token as a header.